# Break synonym between [account-management] and [account-recovery]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Currently, [account-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-recovery) is a synonym of [account-management](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-management).

While I agree that they're related, and sometimes closely so, I suggest that they're sufficiently different that they should not be synonyms.

*Account Management* should cover things like settings and preferences.

*Account Recovery* is for "I've lost access to my account; how do I get it back?" questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed, I have removed this synonym